# Simplify raw sql statement

Tags: android, sqlite

I have the following method in my database class:

```
 public ArrayList<HouseType> getAllHouseTypes(AdvertTypeEnum advertTypeEnum) {
    String language = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
    ArrayList<HouseType> houseTypes = new ArrayList<HouseType>();

    // Get all house types for this advert type
    String selectQuery = "select ht._id, htt." + language + ", htat.api_id " +
            "from house_types ht, house_types_advert_types htat, house_types_translation htt " +
            "where ht._id=htat.house_type_id and ht._id=htt.house_type_id and htat.advert_type=?";

    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[]{String.valueOf(advertTypeEnum.getValue())});

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            HouseType houseType = new HouseType();
            houseType.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(HouseTypesDBContract.HouseTypes.COLUMN_ID)));
            houseType.setApiId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(HouseTypesDBContract.HouseTypesAdvertTypes.COLUMN_API_ID)));
            houseType.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(language)));
            houseType.setAdvertTypeEnum(advertTypeEnum);

            houseTypes.add(houseType);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();

    return houseTypes;
}
```

What is the clean way to perform this query in android? 
It seems to me that replacing the column names with constant would make it a lot more complex so I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this ?

Comment: just offtopic comment: `"...htt." + language + "..."` looks like a bad tables design ... house_types_translation should not looks like  `house_types_translation(house_type_id, lang1, lang2, lang3, langN )` but rather `house_type_id(PK(house_type_id, language), value)` ... now you can choose language in where statment ... also you are using "old joins" `from tab1, tab2 where tab1.pk = tab2.fk` use joins like `from tab1 inner join tab2 on tab1.pk = tab2.fk`

Answer (score 0):

Use defined constants for column names(instead of hard-coding within the strings). 
This is highly recommended if you use the column names in multiple places. Even otherwise it is recommended.

Nothing wrong in hard coding the strings. But instead use string with concatenated constants and you can format the query in better way in multiple lines for readability.

Since you are having a query with multiple tables joined, raw query is the right way.

> constants are recommended mostly because, these column names are
>   generally referred in multiple places. and before release, if you are
>   planing to change the column names, it becomes very easy.